# I am trying to send Jenkins data with InfluxDB plugin into the InfluxDB; it displays 'unauthorized access'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, influxdb

[InfluxDB Plugin] Collecting data...
[InfluxDB Plugin] Publishing data to target 'POC' (url='http://localhost:8086/', database='SOP')
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
com.influxdb.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: unauthorized access
at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractRestClient.responseToError(AbstractRestClient.java:114)
at com.influxdb.internal.AbstractRestClient.execute(AbstractRestClient.java:83)
at com.influxdb.client.internal.AbstractWriteBlockingClient.write(AbstractWriteBlockingClient.java:85)
at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.lambda$writePoints$1(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:137)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723)
at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.writePoints(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:137)
at com.influxdb.client.internal.WriteApiBlockingImpl.writePoints(WriteApiBlockingImpl.java:121)
at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublicationService.writeToInflux(InfluxDbPublicationService.java:397)
Caused: jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxReportException
at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublicationService.writeToInflux(InfluxDbPublicationService.java:400)
at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublicationService.perform(InfluxDbPublicationService.java:330)
at jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxDbPublisher.perform(InfluxDbPublisher.java:227)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:767)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.cleanUp(Build.java:189)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1947)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:107)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:449)
Build step 'Publish build data to InfluxDB' marked build as failure

Environment: Windows, Google Chrome, [image]

Expected Result: Jenkins data shall display in the InfluxDB/Graphs

Actual Result: While I test connection it displays success but upon running it displays 'ERROR: Build step failed with exception com.influxdb.exceptions.UnauthorizedException: unauthorized access'

On the InfluxDB side it displays 'Jenkins' under measurements but it says no result on submit